# Facebook-like anchor scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, anchor

Facebook has a nice scroll effect which I would like to replicate with jQuery. When you load a page it starts at the top then scrolls to the selected anchor.

I've tried doing this (page.html#anchor) and using the scrolling plugin for jQuery however it just goes straight to that anchor without using the scroll effect.

So can I delay the scroll when the page is loaded then use jQuery to do the scrolling instead?

I apologise if I have explained it badly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/09/animated-scrolling-with-jquery-12

basically, you're going to want to animate the scrollTop CSS property.

```
$(document).animate({scrollTop: AMOUNT}, 1000);
```

Comment: But when I load the page it scrolls straight to that element. I want it to wait until the page loads then animate the scroll.

Comment: just wrap that in a 

$(document).ready(function() {
  [code]
});

Could also bind it to any other event really. The possibilities are limitless.